# Inserting ListView Template in a section of the Homepage using Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a ListView Template in Django 1.11 that renders to group_list.html. However I want the same view to show in a column in the home page

I also have screenshots below if that helps understanding what I am trying to achieve

I have tried different ways to use `{% include 'some.html' %}` 
1) I tried to make a html page and include it in homepage. but it keeps giving errors 
2) I tried to change the group_list.html page into a (insert template) that and tried to insert that, in both the index page and created another template view for groups. but that is giving errors too

```
Below are my views and templates
```

**Views.py**

```
 class GroupCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Group
    fields = ('name', 'description')


class GroupList(ListView):
    model = Group


class GroupDetail(DetailView):
    model = Group
```

Below is my Index.html and group_list.html

**INDEX.HTML**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:white; border-right:1px solid grey;">
        <h4>Groups</h4>
        <p>Join a group or make a new Group.</p>
            <a style="float:left" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'groups:new' %}">Start a Group</a>
        <div class="content">
            <!--{ % include 'groups/some.html' % } I am trying to insert my -->
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="col-md-4" style=background-color:white">
    <h4>Second Coloumn</h4>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is my group_list.html

```
{% extends 'groups/group_base.html' %}
{% block pre_group %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
        <h2>Welcome Back
        <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">{{group.user.username}}</a>
        </h2>
        <h3>Groups</h3>
        <p>Welcome to the groups page! Select the Group with the shared interest</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'groups:new' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create a New Group</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for group in object_list %}
        <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug  %}">
            <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{group.name}}</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
                {{group.description_html|safe}}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{group.members.count}}</span> member{{group.members.count|pluralize}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{group.posts.count}}</span> post{{group.posts.count|pluralize}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The HomePage View comes from the root Views they are below

**View.py(root directory)**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class LoggedIn(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'

class LoggedOut(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thanks.html'
```

I am still learning Django while working on my 1st independent project. I did a some research but could not solve this

[I want a list view like this to show on a section of the HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slymj.png)

[Currently the view works perfectly well on the groups page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKqji.jpg)

Comment: Please show the view for your homepage

Comment: @Alasdair I have added the views of the homepage above, Thanks for helping solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your homepage view you can override `get_context_data` and add the groups to the context.

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)     
        context['object_list'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context
```

In the `index.html`, you'll have to copy the code from your `group_list.html` template. To prevent duplication, you could move the code from the content block into a `include_groups.html` template, then use `{% include 'include_groups.html' %} in your`index.html`and`group_list.html` templates.

In this case, since your `Homepage` view is just a template view, you could use a `ListView` instead.

```
class Homepage(ListView):
    model = Group
    template = 'index.html'
```

Whichever option you go for, it's useful to understand how to override `get_context_data` in class based views.

Comment: Yes that did it. Thanks !!